# Nodejs external server error connection

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http

I have one main server which have all files and information and i have build another nodejs project to serve images. When i am trying to connect with it i see `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:2000/addImageURL.The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:8754' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8754' is therefore not allowed access.`. 
To connect i am using angular with `$http`. On the server i have white listed my 8754 port like below.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8754');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    next();
});
```

## Update

If i modify all urls to `127.0.0.1` then i get below error: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/addImageURL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8754' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Are you using Expressjs in the server side?

Comment: It is happened because of cross origin issue. Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Yes, i am using express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', *);`

If it works, it meant the url you have provided for the cross origin `'http://127.0.0.1:8754'` is wrong.

Comment: when i am putting * in '*' i am getting error on client side: `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://127.0.0.1/addImageURL. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8754' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: ok, i found my fail part of code :) Miss to give port inside post from client side.